# Basic JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, web, onclick

just starting with JavaScript and trying to teach myself through simple exercises. I have made this very simple little program which works as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Exercise</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function doSomething(){

            alert("you clicked the text");

            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="text" onclick="doSomething()"> This is some text </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

When you click the text, the alert appears. Then I have modified it slightly to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Exercise 2</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            var whenClicked = document.getElementById("text");

            whenClicked.onclick = doSomething();

            function doSomething(){

                alert("you clicked the text");
            }

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <p id="text"> This is some text </p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Expecting it to work exactly in the same way, but when I load the document on the web browser, the alert appears straight away, without me clicking on the text. Why is this happening? Thanks P.

Comment: (Once you fix that, your next problem is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element))

Comment: #Skillz @Quentin :)

Comment: Great @Quentin for mentioning what'll be his immediate next question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there´s on little error in your code. you have to change:

```
whenClicked.onclick = doSomething();
```

to

```
whenClicked.onclick = doSomething;
```

this is happening because when the brackets are there the function get´s executed imidiatly